# Overwriting JSON file in React/TypeScript/Webpack

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am working on a react project and I read json file with no problem. I can also make changes on that. But when it comes to writing it back I cant do it. I have tried fs.writefile but it wont work either. There is a sample code, I can only make file download, which is not what I want. Hope you guys can help

```
public CreateEntry(){
    var txt = JSON.stringify(data);
    var parsedtxt = JSON.parse(txt || '{}');
    var indexLength = parsedtxt.kitaplar.length;

    var book = document.getElementById("createName") as HTMLInputElement;
    var writer = document.getElementById("createWriter") as HTMLInputElement;
    var publisher = document.getElementById("createPublisher") as HTMLInputElement;

    parsedtxt.kitaplar.push({
        "kitap": book.value,
        "yazar": writer.value,
        "yayinevi": publisher.value
    });

    var resultTxt = JSON.stringify(parsedtxt);
    var file = new File([resultTxt],"kitap.json", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    FileSaver.saveAs(file);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers don't provide APIs to access filesystem. So unfortunately, writing to files is not currently possible.

There was a Filesystem API spec but it is [no longer being standardized.](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2014AprJun/0010.html)

Answer (score 0):

How are you implementing `fs.writeFile`?

Take in account that first you have to require the functionality: `const fs = require('fs');`

Then the code should be something like this:
`fs.writeFile('localFile.json', json, 'utf8', modifiedJson);`

Comment: I imported just like you said and used this code, `fs.writeFile('kitap.json', resultTxt, 'utf8', function (err: any) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }     
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        });`    but it gives Uncaught TypeError: fs.writeFile is not a function error

Comment: I also try to use browserify-fs, and it seems like it worked but it also says that file is saved on index.js. Unfortunately it is not there... and I cant change the directory